# Definition of the homomorphism $\textrm{Gal}(k_s/k) \rightarrow \textrm{Aut}(\psi_0(G))$

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a connected, reductive group over a field $k$.  Identify $G$ with its $\overline{k}$-points.  Let $\Gamma = \textrm{Gal}(k_s/k) = \textrm{Aut}(\overline{k}/k)$.  Let $B$ be a Borel subgroup of $G$, and let $T$ be a maximal torus of $G$.  The choice of $B, T$ give us a based root datum $\psi_0(G)$.  An *automorphism* of $\psi_0(G)$ is an automorphism $X(T) \rightarrow X(T)$ which stabilizes the base of roots corresponding to $B$, and whose dual map stabilizes the base of coroots.

To define the L-group $^L G$, one first defines a homomorphism $\mu_G: \Gamma \rightarrow \textrm{Aut}(\psi_0(G))$.  My question is about the precise definition of this homomorphism.

In the article *Automorphic L-functions* (Corvallis proceedings, Vol II), Borel simply says that for $\gamma \in \Gamma$, $\mu_G(\gamma)$ arises from finding a $g \in G$ such that $\textrm{Int } g \circ \gamma(B) = B$ and $\textrm{Int } g \circ \gamma(T) = T$.

In Kevin Buzzard's note here ([http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/research/notes/forms_of_reductive_algebraic_groups.pdf](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ebuzzard/maths/research/notes/forms_of_reductive_algebraic_groups.pdf)), more detail is given: once $g$ is chosen, one defines $\mu(g)(\chi)$ (for $\chi \in X(T)$) to be the composition $\gamma^{-1} \circ \chi \circ \textrm{Int } g \circ \gamma$.  It does not depend on the choice of $g$.  This follows from the fact that $B' \cap N_G(T') = T'$ for any Borel subgroup $B'$ with maximal torus $T'$.

However, it seems that $\mu_g$, as defined as above, is not actually a homomorphism (into $\textrm{Aut}(X(T))$), but an *anti*-homomorphism: given $\gamma_i \in \Gamma$ and $g_i \in G$ ($i = 1, 2$) such that $\textrm{Int } g_i \circ \gamma_i(B) = B$, one checks that conjugation by $g_2 \gamma_2(g_1)$ sends $\gamma_2 \gamma_1(B)$ to $B$ and $\gamma_2 \gamma_1(T)$ to $T$.  Therefore,

$$\mu(\gamma_2 \gamma_1)(\chi) = (\gamma_2 \circ \gamma_1)^{-1} \circ  \chi \circ \textrm{Int }(g_2 \gamma_2(g_1)) \circ (\gamma_2 \circ \gamma_1)$$

$$ = \gamma_1^{-1} \circ \gamma_2^{-1} \circ \chi \circ \textrm{Int }g_2 \circ \gamma_2 \circ \textrm{Int }g_1 \circ \gamma_1$$

$$ = \mu_G(\gamma_1)(\gamma_2^{-1} \circ \chi \circ \textrm{Int }g_2 \circ \gamma_2)$$

$$ = \mu_G(\gamma_1)(\mu_G(\gamma_2)(\chi)) = \mu_G(\gamma_1) \circ \mu_G(\gamma_2)(\chi)$$

On the other hand, we can change the definition of *automorphism of root datum* to be an isomorphism on the dual $X_{\ast}(T)$ which permutes the simple coroots and whose dual permutes the simple roots.  The dual transform gives an anti-isomorphism between automorphisms of root data in the first sense and the second sense.  Thought of this way, $\mu_G$ **is** a homomorphism $\Gamma \rightarrow \textrm{Aut}(\psi_0(G))$ (that is, $\gamma \mapsto \mu_G(\gamma)^t$ is a homomorphism).

So my questions are:

> 1 .  In what sense is $\mu_G$ a homomorphism?  Should we change the definition of $\mu_G$ from above?  For example, one can instead choose $g$ such that $\textrm{Int }g \circ \gamma^{-1}B = B$ and $\textrm{Int }g \circ \gamma^{-1}T = T$.  Then $\gamma \mapsto (\chi \mapsto \gamma \circ \chi \circ \textrm{Int } g \circ \gamma^{-1})$ *does* define a homomorphism $\Gamma \rightarrow \textrm{Aut}(X(T))$.  Or, should we keep the definition of $\mu_G$ and change the definition of automorphism of root datum?
>
> 2 .  Once we establish the definition $\mu(\gamma)$ as a homomorphism $\Gamma \rightarrow \textrm{Aut}(X(T))$ (or perhaps $\textrm{Aut}(X_{\ast}(T))$), I am stuck on the details of why $\mu(\gamma)$ actually permutes the roots and coroots, i.e. why we know that this is actually an automorphism of root data.  I had thought to emulate the proof that if $\phi \in \textrm{Aut}(G,B,T)$, then $\chi \mapsto \chi \circ \phi$ defines an automorphism of based root data, but I have been unsuccessful.  Why is $\mu_G(\gamma)$ an automorphism of root data?

Thank you.

Comment: The first "mistake" is identifying a variety over $k$ with a set of $\overline{k}$-points; as I wrote elsewhere, this should never be done. Via schemes, the natural Galois action on the character lattice should be *defined* as pullback along the Galois action on $k_s$: the contravariance of Spec cancels the contravariance of pullback to yield covariance; i.e., an action, not an anti-action. For a discussion addressing the role of the Weyl group and coroots, read section 12.2 (especially after the proof of Prop. 12.2.7) in https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110663

Comment: See Prop. 3.1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.1329). It explains how the semi-direct product ${\rm Aut}(G_s)\rtimes{\rm Gal}(k_s/k)$ acts on the based root datum ${\rm BRD}(G_s,T_s,B_s)$. Here $G_s=G\times_k k_s$, $T_s\subset G_s$ is a maximal torus of $G_s$, and $B_s\subset G_s$ is a Borel subgroup containing $T_s$.

Comment: You should try to understand yourself, what a morphism (or at least an automorphism) of a based root datum is. After that it will be clear to you that any automorphism of a triple $(G_s,T_s,B_s)$ as above induces an automorphism of the based root datum ${\rm BRD}(G_s,T_s,B_s)$.

Comment: (cont) Indeed, $\phi$ takes $T_s$ and ${\rm Lie}(G_s)$ to itself, hence it takes the root system $R(G_s,T_s)$ to itself. Since $\phi$ takes $B_s$ to itself, it takes the set of positive roots $R^+(G_s,T_s,B_s)$ to itself, hence it takes the simple roots to the simple roots. The simple coroots are defined in terms of simple roots.

Comment: For $\gamma\in \Gamma$ you  can construct a *$\gamma$-semi-automorphism* $s:={\rm inn}(g)\circ\gamma$ of $(G_s,T_s,B_s)$. Then $\gamma$ takes $\chi$ to $\gamma\circ\chi\circ s^{-1}$. The definition of the action in the notes to which you refer is erroneous, because it is not a homomorphism

Comment: Thanks.  With your definition, I've managed to work out the details

Comment: This is a general formula: If a group $G$ acts on sets $X$ and $Y$, then $G$ acts on the set ${\rm Maps}(X,Y)$ by the following very symmetric formula: $(gf)(gx)=g(f(x))$, which is the same as $(gf)(x)=g(f(g^{-1}x))$. Here $x\in X$, $g\in G$, and $f\in{\rm Maps}(X,Y)$.